# How can I take custom printer settings from one computer and transfer them to others on the network?

Tags: network, printing

I have a new printer on the network with four paper trays. If I set custom print settings on one computer. How can I transfer these setting to other computers?

Answer (score 4):

Find the file

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.print.custompresets.forprinter.(your printer name)
```

and copy it to the other computer into the same location.